# Создание расширения для Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, json, chrome-extension, webapp2

В общем сделал я такое расширение: при переходе по определенным URL пользователю выскакивает сообщение о необходимости включить VPN пере операцией на сайте.
Хотелось бы чтобы высвечивался список с именами организаций и при выборе той или иной на компьютере активировался VPN с тем же названием что и организация.
НА компьютере уже установлены 4 ikev 2 соединения VPN. Операционка под Win10

Comment: Под организацией вы понимаете текущий домен?

Comment: да нет просто текстовый список 4 организации ООО при нажатии на нее активируется скрипт, код и у нас просто активируется нужное подключение